# How can I plot the absolute value of a quantity with colorbar?

Tags: matlab, colorbar, colormap

I am trying to figure out how to use `colorbar` to show the magnitude rather than the value. Currently colorbar has a range from [-x x] where any negative values are color blue-ish. I want the colorbar to ignore the sign values when determining what color to paint the graph.

I tried setting the range to `[0 x]` in `CLim` but that just paints anything that is negative blue.

An example would be plotting a sphere. If you plot a sphere, it would be centered 
at the origin and the color would only reflect the value of the z-axis. However, I want the colorbar to show the magnitude of the distance from the center. So, in this case, the sphere should be a solid color representing the radius.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using a scatter plot, you can use `scatter(t,x,[],abs(x)), colorbar`. You may want to include some more information about what you are trying to plot by posting an example.

Comment: I'd also suggest using abs(matrix), where matrix is your data. Works for all plotting routines including pcolor and contourf.

Comment: There are ways to modify the colorbar, but these normally removes some of the automatic functionality for matlab plots (for example does manual tick labels remove automatic update of the tick labels, when the figure is resized. This leads to that the given tick labels are wrapped around). These things does also require some work to make it look good. This is why modifying the plot data is recommended. Then you can just let matlab plot what you give as an input. If you want to plot the absolute value, then it makes sense to have the absolute values as input:)

Answer (score 1):

You must take the magnitude of the data you are plotting (e.g. using the `abs(data)` function) prior to making a figure with it. Then, you can set the colorbar scale using the `caxis([min max])` function.

Example:

```
rawData=repmat([-10:1:10],10,1);

figure(1),imagesc(rawData),caxis([0 10]) % All raw values below 0 are plotted as blue

magnData=abs(rawData) % Take absolute value of raw data

figure(2),imagesc(magnData),caxis([0 10]) % Raw negative values are now plotted in the same color as positive raw values (i.e. ignoring the sign, per the solution you requested).
```

Your solution (`CLim`) didn't work because setting the color range `[0 x]` will associate color of all values lower than `0` to the value of `0` (blue, in the case of the "jet" colormap).

Comment: Would this still be applicable in 3D plotting?